# Making a Mobile friendly website

Tags: javascript, css, html

When you go to the facebook newsfeed page in your browser, you see a cool mobile interface that looks like an app.

So how to do that kind of website?  Which has this application like interface?

Is it with html, lots of html5, Javascript, css?

Comment: FYI: People downvote questions that show little to no research effort, or they think are unclear/not useful.  See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for useful info on what makes good questions.

Comment: I tried searching but it was too unclear!

Comment: First of all, you didn't ask "Why did I get downvoted." You sarcastically said "Thanks for the thumbs down :(". Second, the downvotes are because you asked a question ill-suited to Stack Overflow. SO is primarily for coding/debugging help. If you don't have any code to debug or get help with, you're probably not going to get much help, as is demonstrated with this question. Lastly, it doesn't show much research effort. SO encourages self-learning with help when you need it. We're not here to teach you from step one, we're here to assist you when you can't get past step N. Anything else?

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate you taking the time to try and better your understanding of the web, however I'd like to ask that you take some time to write thoughtful grammatically correct questions in the future.

That being said:

Yes, it is done in html, javascript, and css as is everything on the web. You can do it yourself using the "screen" [Media Query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) or you can use frameworks such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which allow you to build mobile friendly websites in a very easy and intuitive fashion.

> The **screen media query** allows you to apply css based on the size of
>   the screen.

Example (click full page to see change):

```css
button{
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        button{
            font-size: 12px;

        }
    }
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

If you're interested and becoming a better mobile developer; I'd recommend that you download one of these frameworks, follow a few tutorials, and play around with them for a bit, and then once you've seen how they work try writing your own simpler version using the css media queries.

Comment: Keep posting good answers like this and it won't take long for the rep to build! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Edited you answer to provide the Foundation link you couldn't use.

Comment: Thanks @Chris! I've been using StackOverflow for years now, and I thought it was about time to create a profile on it.

Comment: @TimLewis, thanks for adding the link. I had a bit of an OCD moment when I couldn't post the third link. Hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Use @media queries in CSS to develop different interfaces for different sized devices.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp